# Error convert Oracle ldr to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dataframe

I'm trying convert a ldr Oracle file into a pandas Dataframe, to get some insights.

I have the following string 'example' into my txt file. Where, '|' character represents the field separator and '{EOL}' the delimiter line.

countries.txt (file)

```
"USA"|"111"| {EOL}"ITALY"|"222"| {EOL}"MEXICO"|"333"|{EOL}
```

What I already tried was:

```
new_element=[]
new_element2=[]
csvfile = open('d:\countries.txt')
for line in csvfile 
    new_lines = line.split('|{EOL}')
for i in new_lines 
    new_element.append(i)
for j in new_element:
    new_element2.append(j.replace('"','\'').replace('|',','))
del(new_element2[3])
```

After executing the previous commands, we got it:

```
new_element2
["'USA','111'", "'ITALY','222'", "'MEXICO','333'"]
```

As next step, we are trying convert this "list" to a DataFrame, using the following command:

```
pd_element = pd.DataFrame(new_element2,columns=['a','b'])
```

but, in this moment an error message appears to us:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1650                 blocks = [make_block(values=blocks[0],
-> 1651                                      placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))]
   1652 

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   3094 
-> 3095     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3096 

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
   2630         super(ObjectBlock, self).__init__(values, ndim=ndim,
-> 2631                                           placement=placement)
   2632 

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
     86                 'Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies '
---> 87                 '{mgr}'.format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs)))
     88 

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-446-cec97633cd5d> in <module>
----> 1 pd_element = pd.DataFrame(new_outro,columns=['a','b'])

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    449                 else:
    450                     mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
--> 451                                        copy=copy)
    452             else:
    453                 mgr = init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    165         values = maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(values)
    166 
--> 167     return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values], [columns, index])
    168 
    169 

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1658         blocks = [getattr(b, 'values', b) for b in blocks]
   1659         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1660         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1661 
   1662 

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1689         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   1690     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 1691         passed, implied))
   1692 
   1693 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 2)
```

After some searches, we found this tutorial explaining, we bealive, the same problem that we have and, the solution about our problem: https://datatofish.com/list-to-dataframe/

```
from pandas import DataFrame

    People_List = [['Jon','Smith',21],['Mark','Brown',38],['Maria','Lee',42],['Jill','Jones',28],['Jack','Ford',55]]
    
    df = DataFrame (People_List,columns=['First_Name','Last_Name','Age'])
    print (df)
```

It works fine!!!

We are observing that the problem is the same: We have a list and wish convert then, into a DataFrame.
We understood that part of our problem happening during ldr convert file to list but, unfortunately, we cannot understand "why".

Dears, if someone can pass to us a site whit kind of manual that enable us improve our understand about what is happening, we give you thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to solve my problem
Following the answer:

```
head = ['field1','field2']
new_element=[]
new_element2 = []
csvfile = open('d:\countries.txt')
for line in csvfile 
    new_lines = line.split('|{EOL}')
    for j in new_element:
        new_element2.append(re.sub('"','',j)).split('|')
df = DataFrame(new_element2, head)
df.to_parquet('file.parquet')
```

In my case, I worked with a "right" data quantity being necessary convert, fisrt, in a DataFrame and persisting as parquet file.